# PDF Font Embedding Significantly Affecting File Size

Tags: pdf, printing, fonts, rdlc, truetype

I have a PDF which uses 'Calibri' as a font.  Our printers insist that it must be embedded into the document, however when we do the PDF is approximately 3x larger.

We initially thought there isn't much we can do about this, but the printers sent over a document which has *both* 'Calibri' embedded *and* the smaller file size.

The difference between the two can be seen here:

[image: Before]

**Ours**

[image: After]

**Printers**

It's clear that embedded Fonts are the culprit here.

**How can we produce PDFs with this smaller file size?**

The library we are using is `Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms` but I suspect we may need to do some post-processing to reduce the sizes, therefore do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Is yours just embedded and theirs embedded and subsetted?

Comment: Both seem to be 'embedded subset'